# stream_set_blocking() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, laravel-5.3, swiftmailer

I want to sent emails from online server with Laravel 5.4. I don't know if the problem is with my code or the server. I have hosting from easyname.com.

This is my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.easyname.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=info@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypasword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

This is my config/mail.php file

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.easyname.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'info@mydomain.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'My Name'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', ''),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

When I try to run the code, it gives me the following error. I don't know where I am making the mistake.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by just changing MAIL_DRIVER from `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` to `MAIL_DRIVER=mail` in both the .env file and mail.php file. Also change MAIL_ENCRYPTION from `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=` to `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, try:

1. The cloud virtual machine environment does not support `stream_socket_client` function.
2. Just change it to fsockopen function. port is 465 ssl, because 25 will be banned. Similar to the `$this->stream = @fsockopen($host, $this->params['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout)`
3. Open fsockopen function in Cloud virtual machine background.

Answer (score 0):

[`stream_set_blocking()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php) expects a resource on which to act as its first parameter. Your error occurs when that resource is non-existent.  This in turn is likely because the socket connection could not open successfully.

The problematic line is likely from `AbstractSmtpTransport.php, line 113`:

```
Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(
    ['protocol'=>'', 'host'=>'smtp.easyname.com', 'port'=>465...]
)
```

I'm not familiar with this library but I bet that this was supposed to return an open socket, but it failed, `null` was returned, and the library never checked for success before using the socket in `stream_set_blocking()`

I would start by investigating why the protocol is an empty string, and what it should be.