# Swift Mailer not working on easyname.com: `stream_set_blocking()` error

Tags: php, symfony, email, swiftmailer

When trying to use [Swift Mailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/) at the Austrian hoster easyname (easyname.com or easyname.at), I'm getting the following error from `vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php` (line 275)

> Warning: stream_set_blocking() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

This "parameter 1" should be a stream resource, opened by [`stream_socket_client()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php) in Swift Mailer's [`StreamBuffer::establishSocketConnection()`](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php#L267).

Until [version 4.0.7](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/releases/tag/4.0.7) (June 2011), Swift Mailer was using [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php).

Thanks to [this forum post (in German)](https://community.contao.org/de/showthread.php?62008-Erfahrungsbericht-easyname-at&s=7fc18679d34222117b784f56c95ca091&p=492968&viewfull=1#post492968) for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

easyname's support informed me today that they disabled `stream_socket_client()` in PHP7.x to prevent abuse by hackers. This is their last word.

For clarification: It doesn't matter if you use easyname's own mail server for Swift Mailer or any external mail server. Swift Mailer will not work. Period.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using easyname.at and I solved it by setting `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` to `MAIL_DRIVER=mail`
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45405743/3447279